# Unknown error when matching passwords

Tags: php

The following code is for a sign up form and comes auto generated from WYSIWYG Web builder. It keeps saying `password` and `confirmpassword` are not the same. I don't know anything of PHP so I can't find the error.

I need help with this  :

```
<?php $mysql_server = 'db4free.net';
$mysql_username = '----';

$mysql_password = '----';
$mysql_database = '----';
$mysql_table = 'userdb';
$success_page = './userpage.php';
$error_message = "";
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $_POST['form_name'] == 'signupform')
{
   $newusername = $_POST['username1'];
   $newemail = $_POST['email'];
   $newpassword = $_POST['password1'];
   $confirmpassword = $_POST['confirmpassword'];
   $newfullname = $_POST['fullname'];
   $code = 'NA';
   if ($newpassword!= $confirmpassword)
   {
      $error_message = 'Password and Confirm Password are not the same!';
   }
   else
   if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$/", $newusername))
   {
      $error_message = 'Username is not valid, please check and try again!';
   }
   else
   if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$]{1,50}$/", $newpassword))
   {
      $error_message = 'Password is not valid, please check and try again!';
   }
   else
   if (!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9_!@$.' &]{1,50}$/", $newfullname))
   {
      $error_message = 'Fullname is not valid, please check and try again!';
   }
   else
   if (!preg_match("/^.+@.+\..+$/", $newemail))
   {
      $error_message = 'Email is not a valid email address. Please check and try again.';
   }
   if (empty($error_message))
   {
      $db = mysql_connect($mysql_server, $mysql_username, $mysql_password);
      if (!$db)
      {
         die('Failed to connect to database server!<br>'.mysql_error());
      }
      mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $db) or die('Failed to select database<br>'.mysql_error());
      $sql = "SELECT username FROM ".$mysql_table." WHERE username = '".$newusername."'";
      $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
      if ($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
      {
         $error_message = 'Username already used. Please select another username.';
      }
   }
   if (empty($error_message))
   {
      $crypt_pass = md5($newpassword);
      $newusername = mysql_real_escape_string($newusername);
      $newemail = mysql_real_escape_string($newemail);
      $newfullname = mysql_real_escape_string($newfullname);
      $sql = "INSERT `".$mysql_table."` (`username`, `password`, `fullname`, `email`, `active`, `code`) VALUES ('$newusername', '$crypt_pass', '$newfullname', '$newemail', 1, '$code')";
      $result = mysql_query($sql, $db);
      mysql_close($db);
      $subject = 'Your new account';
      $message = 'A new account has been setup.';
      $message .= "\r\nUsername: ";
      $message .= $newusername;
      $message .= "\r\nPassword: ";
      $message .= $newpassword;
      $message .= "\r\n";
      $header  = "From: webmaster@yourwebsite.com"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Reply-To: webmaster@yourwebsite.com"."\r\n";
      $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8"."\r\n";
      $header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit"."\r\n";
      $header .= "X-Mailer: PHP v".phpversion();
      mail($newemail, $subject, $message, $header);
      header('Location: '.$success_page);
      exit;
   }
}
?>
```

Comment: ow if you want to check : http://project-shelby.tk/login.php

Comment: Are you sure the username and password you're using is correct?

Comment: Are you sure the passwords being inserted are the exact same?

Comment: Check html source for form...

Comment: You don't have a form field with the name password1 in that page. There's a field with an id of password1, but that has a name of password.

Comment: that's a good example why should code OOP with proper classes and exceptions

Comment: @DanFromGermany OOP is great, but it won't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the field 'password1' is actually 'password'. Only the id is 'password1', but that isn't used in the post data.

Answer (score 0):

The name of the field for password is "password". Same for the username field.

You should change the lines:

```
$newusername = $_POST['username1'];
$newpassword = $_POST['password1'];
```

to:

```
$newusername = $_POST['username'];
$newpassword = $_POST['password'];
```

Comment: What you said was wrong i did it good but i forgot to rename the texboxes. Thnx for all the help! :)